# Calculate time within SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, time

I run a opening-hours site where we present data if a store is open or not.

So far I do the calculation if it's open or not in PHP, but I am wondering if it's possible to do directly in the query. This would speed it up a lot as I don't have to fetch all the rows (over 10.000) to only present open ones, but can limit the query directly.

The format is:

```
HH:MM-HH:MM
08:00-16:00
```

Table fields:

```
mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun
```

So the query needs to know which day it is, split the field to calculate if it's within current time.

Currently in PHP I just split them by ':' and '-' and work it out from there.

Comment: do not do in this way, instead may two columns for that , open and close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a horrible table structure. You should be storing the open/close times in SEPARATE fields as proper time values. e.g.

```
create table storehours (
   id int auto_increment primary key,
   storeID int,
   open time,
   closed time
);
```

Then you can do an extremely simple:

```
SELECT storeID
WHERE curtime() BETWEEN open AND closed
```

Comment: The problem is that the stores obviously don't open/close the same time all day of the week. Then I would need 7 rows, per store. Currently 12.000 stores, which would create a table of 84.000 rows

Comment: 84k rows isn't all that much for a proper database. you can always add a 'day' field to track what days that applies for - no record for a particular day = closed.

Comment: Alright. I know the structure used atm is very poorly made and was just to get going, guess I'll redo it. Thank you.

Comment: @EmilVictorDayan 84k rows would not be a problem. If you get a question in the future which stores are open till 21:00 and on what days you can save yourself a lot of trouble if you do it like MarcB suggests (and adding a day-field).

Comment: How should the time for open/close be stored? 08:00?

Comment: as a native mysql time value, e.g. `hh:mm:ss`, using a 24hour clock

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: split your current column into two separate columns (eg. `open` and `close`).

Step 2: `SELECT * FROM shops WHERE HOUR(NOW()) BETWEEN open AND close;`

Alternatively, you can split the column on-the-fly:

```
SELECT * FROM shops
WHERE HOUR(NOW()) BETWEEN
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(openclose, '-', 1) AND
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(openclose, '-', -1);
```

But really, split your columns, the above query is unable to make use of any index on your column.

---

Accounting for the case where stores have different opening times for each day.

```sql
CREATE TABLE opening_times (
   store_id INT NOT NULL,
   day_of_week INT NOT NULL, -- 1 = Sunday
   open TIME NOT NULL,
   close TIME NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (store_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store(id),
   INDEX (day_of_week, open, close) -- suggested index
);

SELECT store.* FROM opening_times
JOIN store ON store.id = opening_times.store_id
WHERE
    DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = day_of_week
    AND HOUR(NOW()) BETWEEN open AND close
```

Answer (score 0):

@marc-b is right. but missing.

```
create table storehours (
   id int auto_increment primary key,
   storeID int,
   dayId int,
   open time,
   closed time
);

insert into `storehours` (`id`, `storeID`, `dayId`, `open`, `closed`) VALUES
(1, 123, 5, '09:00:00', '18:00:00'),
(2, 456, 6, '12:00:00', '19:00:00');

SELECT storeID from storehours
WHERE dayId = dayofweek(now()) and curtime() BETWEEN open AND closed
```